# How can I best display code samples in Word 2007?

Tags: ms-word

I would like the code samples to have line numbers, a border, a background color, and be in courier. The code samples should be able to span pages, so a text box may not be the best solution. Is there a style sheet available for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Visual Studio?  If so, then you should just be able to cut & paste it from the VS-IDE to word.  Since the VS-IDE code Copy is in rich-text form, Word will preserve the formatting when it is pasted in.  I do it this way all the time (including with SQL) and it works far better than anything else that I have come up with.

(If you're not using Visual Studio, then sorry, I do not know.)

Answer (score 0):

While its not the best way to do things, one popular approach is to just take a screen shot of your window in your favorite editor and embed the image in the word document.

Comment: God no, how could you copy and paste from a document like this?

Comment: I never said that it was a good way to do it. Just a popular one.

Answer (score 0):

paste -> special -> unformatted text ?